# After adding a new device to home network, my chromebook is having connection issues

Tags: wireless-networking, ip, arp

I have multiple devices connected to my Wi-Fi router (Archer C7 by TP-Link). I have never had trouble before going into my settings and now I cannot tell what I did wrong so that I can fix it without resetting my whole setup.

My devices on my original setup were the following and everything was fine :

- 2 cellphones
- 1 Chromebook
- 1 tower

Then:

- I added 1 Raspberry Pi with a fixed IP address — let’s say it was `192.168.0.10` — so that I could run a DDNS server and connect to it from outside my house.

And everything was fine still. But this is where I started having troubles:

- Bought an Amazon FireTV Stick and lost connection a couple of days later.

I found out that my Chromebook had the same IP address as my FireTV stick, but why?

I did change its address for a fixed one as well. I don’t understand why I have to do this because forgetting the network and rebooting the router was still giving the same IP address.

Now that I assigned an IP address to my Chromebook, one of my cellphones actually had this IP address too.

Also now I cannot connect to my Raspberry Pi either from PuTTY. Is the IP address conflicting too? (EDIT: the ip address was conflicting)

So my question is:

### When I set some IP and MAC binding settings, does it mean now that I *must* list all of my devices in it regardless of the automatic DHCP?

It looks to me that having two “categories” causes my router to be clueless and it’s just giving the next IP address it thinks there’s available.

Should I just clear the ARP table list, reboot my router and forget the network on all my devices so that the ARP table is fresh? I only have 4 MAC addresses in the ARP table and 1 of them is unbound which I don’t really know what it means.

Comment: The whole raspberry idea is useless, because that router supports DDNS; see the [manual](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/archer-c7/) on page 79. I mean, you probably want to set this up in the router, along with port forwards, because the router is usually always running.

Comment: It certainly answers the question, because the setup is flawed. The question suggests, that nobody read the manual of the router before ...since DHCP pools should be covered there, too.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I agree with you :-) Not only that. He is probably unknowingly running a 2nd DHCP server on the Raspberry Pi as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DHCP servers can usually be configured to assign out of a pool, or range, of addresses. For example, you could have it assign addresses in the range 192.168.0.150 -> 250, and configure your static IP devices numbers below 150.

In my cable-modem router, this setting is under "Advanced Settings >> DHCP settings". The range is defined via "Beginning DHCP address" and "Ending DHCP Address."

So the answer to your question is "no", you can mix dynamic and static addresses by configuring your DHCP server, as described here.

Comment: That makes sense. I was thinking about giving my fixed devices fixed ip addresses manually to higher values but your solution should do the job for me. I'm pretty sure it was it but I wanted to be sure it wasn't something else that I didn't know of – I'm still a student. I will accept once I try it out and that it's really solved. :-)